# Facebook pages and Flash content - autoplay

Tags: facebook, flash, autoplay

I've recently used the 'Static HTML' application to add autoplaying flash content to a Facebook Page. Nothing too fancy, no sound, and only a few secs long. Now, Facebook say:-"Apps on Pages must not host media that plays automatically without a user's interaction."

What do they mean by 'Media' exactly? I can understand a ban on autoplaying audio content but does the ban extend to something as harmless as an animated GIF? Or more to the point, does an autoplaying .swf file fall under this?

Lastly, what course of action would Facebook take if I did violate this rule? Would they issue a warning (giving me an opportunity to remove the 'offending' item) or would they just shut down my page without any consultation?

Desperate for an answer to this one...

Answer (score 0):

I think with "media" Facebook means audio/video. some time ago, they disabled autoplay of Flash and JavaScript anyway (only available on user interaction), now it is possible to start Flash and JavaScript when the iFrame app loads.
So, there should not be a problem to use animated gifs (as long as they are not some megabytes in size) or Flash; As long as Flash does not autoplay movies or audio.

Comment: One could argue that a GIF would also fall into the category of "media" in this case.

Comment: well, let´s just hope that animated gifs don´t come back. except for preloader-gifs, in that case they are fine :) - but facebook does not state this clearly, so i would say it´s safe to use flash and animated gifs.

Comment: Then all I can say is *Good Luck!* :P  Flash definitely falls under the category of media.  GIF's however, that might just me my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that this is a very broad definition or "media".  If you ask me - any form of media that has a "playing" action (this would include animated GIFS) falls under the category of "media".

If you are in doubt. then you probably should not "auto-play" it.   In my opinion animated GIFs are also considered media.  Or, rather one could say that it depends on the GIF.  *Imagine (if you will) a 600x800, 10MB GIF*.

Either way - if facebook finds you to be violating their policy - they will take possible one or more of the following actions :

- Send the administrator of the page/application a warning email.
- Delete/Close your page/application.
- Prevent your user from opening additional pages/applications.
- Prevent your user from accessing facebook pending a verification process.

There is no documentation of the exact actions they will take (that i've found) - this list is from my personal experience from my dealings with facebook.