# How to autoplay embedded Facebook videos?

Tags: facebook, video

This [page](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-facebook-videos-in-web-pages/9715/) shows how to create the embed code for any Facebook video to embed them in external websites.

Is there a way to start the playback automatically on page load?

Answer (score 12):

The best way for me is to use Facebook URL like this: https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/video.php?allowfullscreen=true&autoplay=true&container_width=800&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fredbull%2Fvideos%2F10155801793140352%2F&locale=en_US&sdk=joey

It's better than the embed url. The video fits in viewport, you can control autoplay with a query string/param.

Comment: @abel good luck getting any videos to autoplay now a days on mobile. The answer does however still work on desktop.

Comment: @SlickRemix
on iMessage, Facebook video links are auto play on the mobile (tested on iOS12). So the question is if it's something only iMessage can do or everyone.

Comment: @user1105951 That does makes sense because it's on the facebook platform, however the main question was about embedding facebook videos which entails putting them on your own website.

Comment: iMessage app = Apple platform.
Facebook Messenger = Facebook platform.

Comment: Note: This URL pattern worked for my Google Slides presentation. I did it as a link you click on the slide and it opens in a new tab.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately for you [Facebook's policies](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=facebook%20autoplay%20media#q=facebook%20policy%20%22autoplay%22%20site:facebook.com&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&prmd=imvns&ei=n6ayT9DqF4jDhAezn6Fv&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=9d1b2ebaf21cf886&biw=1920&bih=955) forbid the autoplaying of content (thank god).

I have attempted to track down the actual policy document but it's been drowned out in the SERPS noise of people talking about it being banned on Facebook!! You can find questions that back this notion up on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403320/facebook-pages-and-flash-content-autoplay) and [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17818/what-is-considered-media-when-referring-to-facebook-pages-autoplay-policy).

StackOverflow is the official Facebook developer support channel so their users may know more on the topic.

It's also possible some whizzy jQuery might be able to fake the click, - but facebook updates it's code so often that I doubt any hack would last long.

Best answer is use YouTube or another channel that allows you so share outside their network. Don't rely on a hacky solution for a network that clearly isn't interested in video being shared beyond it's own borders.

Users can easily change the privacy settings on their videos, and Facebook will probably try and disrupt the ability to embed their content if it becomes a popular thing to do.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. One post mentions "Apps on Pages must not host media that plays automatically without a user's interaction." I don't think their policy would apply since I'm playing a Facebook video on my own website.

Comment: @MotoTribe Indeed, I spotted that too, but because of the policy I think the flash player they use can't actually be made to autoplay. I tried a number of the standard embed parameters and it supports none of them.

Comment: looks like facebook has  had done a u-turn on the autoplay policy, as they are rolling out autoplay videos in the newsfeed right now.

Comment: And FB now allow you to autoplay with a simple data attribute on the embed code. I've edited the answer to reflect. If I've done something wrong by doing so, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

For Youtube, add `&autoplay=1` at the end of the URL used to autoplay the video. For example:

If the URL to get to the video is:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/xxx
```

The autoplay URL is:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/xxx&autoplay=1
```

The above works for Youtube, but Facebook is a little different:

In the embed portion of the code to autoplay the video on your site add the following parameter:

```html
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
```

This method works on other sites as well, mostly those that use a Flash-based video player.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't work. Your example is for auto playing youtube videos embedded on facebook. I'm looking to auto play facebook videos embedded in external websites.

Comment: justin is right but &autoplay=1 after the video ID. so...value="http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxx&autoplay=1"

Comment: I'm not trying to embed a youtube video on facebook - I'm trying to embed a facebook video on an external site - and then autoplay it

Comment: @MotoTribe See revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of the latest Facebook SDK today, you are able to autoplay videos passively by adding data-autoplay="true" to the div tag of the embed code.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

I've just implemented this on my own project and it does work but as of right now it will only play passively (in mute mode). This is a similar experience as what you would see if you were scrolling through your news feed on Facebook. The user has to manually unmute the video.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> waitforclick
>
> Indicates whether to autoplay the Flash object (false) when allowed.
> false does not work in profiles for security and aesthetic reasons,
> except after an AJAX call. Default value is true

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/swf/

U have to change the the example code from the bottom to the the facebook video, like in your provided link explained.

Didnt tried it, but maybe it helps

regards

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a video ID, I can't test it, but adding a "play" or "autoplay" parameter may work:

```html
<object width="400" height="224" >
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" />
 <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
 <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224" autoplay="true">
 </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: nope, that doesn't do that trick. 10150683565839444 would be a video ID to test

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are slightly outdated, so just the have the updated answer around, you can see the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player) for all the details.

**TL;DR:**

This is how embedding a video from Facebook Looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title> 
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
  <div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
      <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/">How to Share With Just Friends</a>
        <p>How to share with just friends.</p>
        Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/">Facebook</a> on Friday, December 5, 2014
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The following html tag lets you set autoplay to true:**

```
<div class="fb-video" data-href="<video-post-url>" data-autoplay="true">
```

Default value for `data-autoplay` is of course `false`.

Answer (score -3):

it shouldn't matter which videos you are embedding. adding the code

**&autoplay=1**

to the end of the URL of the video you are embedding should resolve the issu and allow the video to play automatically.

Comment: I've just reviewed the link, I hadn't noticed it before. Adding the line <PARAM NAME=autoplay VALUE=true> to the embedding code should work.