# how to add autoplay in facebook embedded video code?

Tags: php

iam using facebook embedded video code in

```
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151656669927311" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but its not automatically play, i dont wants to click on player's play button/screen... can anybody help me that how it automatically plays when i open this file like utube embedded code, when we pass aytoplay=1 after video id with ? mark in utube embedded code. it plays automatically.. but not same in fb code.. please help me

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoplay embedded Facebook videos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611081/how-to-autoplay-embedded-facebook-videos)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`&autoplay=1` works with **YouTube** but **Facebook** videos won't let you autoplay content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
**xxx** - video id

```
<object width="400" height="224" >
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" />
  <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
  <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224" autoplay="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Stolen from "[How to autoplay embedded Facebook videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611081/how-to-autoplay-embedded-facebook-videos)"

Comment: dear this code is not working when i paste this code, nothing show on browser

Comment: Won't work. FBML was deprecated long time ago. Think before you copy n paste.

Answer (score -1):

just try below method to autoplay, it is working for me

1. grab the src link `https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=xxxx` and open in firefox
   now start the firebug and try looking into the html section
   inside some div you will see embed code like this
   embed width=”100%” height=”100%”
   `https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v1/yE/r/QIsVb0PNxwO.swf&#8221; type=”application/x-shockwave-flash”\>`
   there you will see autoplay%22%3Afalse
   change that to true and the video will autoplay