# Cant get a youtube embedble link to autoplay on Facebook/twitter

Tags: youtube, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I keep trying to get these 2 videos to autoplay on social media like FB or Twitter.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

May be you will find some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611081/how-to-autoplay-embedded-facebook-videos). I do not understand your question. What do you want to do ? If you want to post the videos just copy the links.

Comment: https://youtu.be/j_CLcDJY3Y4                                      https://youtu.be/sxPlOShDzRo                                 These are the 2 links I am tying to make them auto play on social media sites like FB and Twitter